# How to change system locale in batch

Tags: batch-file

So I am trying to make a kirikiri(Japanese virtual novel creator) but the novel won't run unless the system locale is Japanese.

I know how to do it manually; but I would like to create a program writing in batch to speed things up.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? What is your code?

Comment: I don't have the slightest clue on changing a system file and when i googled it nothing came up.

Comment: I think this might be achieved better by a batch file. Java doesn't have access to operating-system specifics like this.

Comment: how in a batch file?

Answer (score 3):

You can set it from the [command line like this](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/locale-140624.html#using):

```
java -Duser.country=CA -Duser.language=fr ... com.x.Main
```

Comment: is that system locale or the Whole system language?

Comment: @Moocow9m:- Its on Java Platform.

Comment: It has to change the system locale you can find in the control panel.

Comment: @Moocow9m:- Did you tried it along with reading the link which I shared?

Comment: just looked.... will it be able to hold the system locale after restart? the program wont be launched by the setup it will just be an installer.

Comment: @Moocow9m:- Yes it will be!

Comment: The OP means that the system locale in Windows (which is what I assume his operating system is) needs to be changed in order for him to be able to run a third-party application. He is *not* talking about the Java locale, just wanting to change the system language by running a Java program.

Comment: @RealSkeptic that would be correct that that is exactly what i am asking and my OS is windows 7.

Comment: @RealSkeptic:- Are you saying that to set default local at runtime by using  Locale.setDefault() Something like this: `System.setProperty("user.language", "sv");
  System.setProperty("user.country", "SE");` Also have a look at the [bug](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7073906)

Comment: I am saying that he is not interested in setting the locale for Java programs, but for a third party, **non-java** application called KiriKiri.

Comment: @RealSkeptic:- Then I am afraid that it is possible or not. As far as I know that is not possible. Doing it from Control Panel is the only option. Even if there is some way then also it is would be complex.

Comment: correct but use java to code a program to change it

Comment: but i have heard of other applications changing system languages so why not locale?

Answer (score 2):

Should have know it would be simple(lol)...

In .bat

```
@echo off
control.exe intl.cpl,,/f:"locale.xml"
echo Files ready! press enter to finish setup!!
pause
shutdown.exe /r /t 00
```

In XML

```
<gs:GlobalizationServices xmlns:gs="urn:longhornGlobalizationUnattend"> 
<gs:UserList>
<gs:User UserID="Current" CopySettingsToDefaultUserAcct="true" CopySettingsToSystemAcct="true"/></gs:UserList> 
<gs:InputPreferences> 

<!--en-AU--><gs:InputLanguageID Action="add" ID="0409:00000c09" Default="true"/>

<!--jp-JP--><gs:InputLanguageID Action="add" ID="0411:{03B5835F-F03C-411B-9CE2-AA23E1171E36}{A76C93D9-5523-4E90-AAFA-4DB112F9AC76}"/>

 </gs:InputPreferences>
 </gs:GlobalizationServices>
```

Comment: Go [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2764405/how-to-automate-regional-and-language-settings-in-windows-vista-window) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/default-input-locales-for-windows-language-packs) to find out more if you want to customize things.