# How to automate open control panel and add a language and move up?

Tags: windows-10-desktop, controlpanel

I am trying to add a language in windows 10 creators update (RS2). 
Now tried using the bat and xml file mentioned here, [How to change system locale in batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30557286/how-to-change-system-locale-in-batch)
, its not working in new OS.  Windows is restarting but not applying and moving up the language. Any other way to update the language through any commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Powershell can do the above given steps in one command.

Simply enter this command and relogin

```
Set-WinUILanguageOverride en-us
```